# Are there freezing issues with the Seagate Barracuda ST31500341AS anymore?

Tags: hard-drive, firmware, seagate

I found this hard drive on NewEgg:

Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 ST31500341AS 1.5TB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive (bare drive) - OEM

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148337

And there are quite a few substantial bad reviews about the drive freezing periodically. If you search for a bit, you can find several forums with people having problems, but of course forums don't get updated when resolutions to those problems are found.

I'm just wondering, does anyone know what the final verdict regarding the freezing issue with these hard drives is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Toms Hardware article](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/seagate-barracuda-1.5TB-freezing,6582.html):

Part numbers for the affected models of Barracuda drives and their respective firmware revisions are as follows:

“Affected part number: 9JU138-300, 336 with firmware revisions SD15, SD17, or SD18.”

It also mentions there's a firmware fix available to treat the problem if you run into it

Answer (score 1):

i'm using 4 drives from problematic series, i just did update of firmware from seagate and so far have no problems.

at least according to vendor problem can be fixed by that.

Answer (score 0):

I have 4 of that model, 3 have have a CC1H firmware and they are not having problems.  One of the drives did have the buggy firmware, I applied the update, and it is still acting a bit odd.

When I run tests on the drive while it is in a computer by itself it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My drive is almost 9000 Power On Hours and only 2 reallocated sectors, but working very well ! I use CC1H firmware.